# PHP Simple DOMDocument scraping exclude td class

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, domdocument

Im simply trying to get all the `<td>` elements data residing inside `<tr>` elements. My problem is because of the table structure im trying to scrape I need to exclude all elements with attribute `COLLSPAN` i.e `<td collspan = 12>` 
Getting the table data is simple enough as can be seen from below code but because of the table structure I need to exclude all collspan attributes.

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.superxv.com/fixtures/'); //get the html returned from the following url

$game_doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors
if(!empty($html)) { //if any html is actually returned
    $game_doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove error
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($game_doc);

    // Modify the XPath query to match the content
    foreach ($xpath->query('//table')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $rows) {
        $cells = $rows->getElementsByTagName('td');
        //$cells2 = $rows->getElementsByTagName('th');
        echo '<pre>';
         //@ signs are added due to table structure
        //Get scrapped columns
        echo $dayDateBye[] = $cells->item(0)->textContent;
        echo $homeTeam[] = $cells->item(1)->textContent;
        echo $awayTeam[] = $cells->item(2)->textContent;
        echo $venue[] = $cells->item(3)->textContent;
        echo $timeGMT[] = $cells->item(5)->textContent;
        echo $timeZA[] = $cells->item(10)->textContent;
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Here you can see the table structure it shows 5 odd rows of fixtures and then changes structure when the new week starts. The elements I can identify to skip over this change of structure is all `<td collspan = 12>` elements. Which makes it tricky since the TD elements does not have a class name only the element to identify it with.

[image]

[image]

Any input appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question, If you want to skip the rows which mentioned as rows, you can do count($cells) == 1, then skip it in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip those by length of the tag

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.superxv.com/fixtures/'); //get the html returned from the following url

$game_doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors
if(!empty($html)) { //if any html is actually returned
    $game_doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove error
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($game_doc);

    // Modify the XPath query to match the content
    foreach ($xpath->query('//table')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $rows) {
        $cells = $rows->getElementsByTagName('td');
        if( $cells->length > 1 ){
            //$cells2 = $rows->getElementsByTagName('th');
            echo '<pre>';
             //@ signs are added due to table structure
            //Get scrapped columns
            echo $dayDateBye[] = $cells->item(0)->textContent;
            echo $homeTeam[] = $cells->item(1)->textContent;
            echo $awayTeam[] = $cells->item(2)->textContent;
            echo $venue[] = $cells->item(3)->textContent;
            echo $timeGMT[] = $cells->item(5)->textContent;
            echo $timeZA[] = $cells->item(10)->textContent;
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Dhayal Im just trying to understand the answer PLEASE could you explain how exactly does`if( $cells->length > 1 ){` correlate to skipping by length of tag. WORKS GREAT THANKS!

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee, We are looping the rows(tr). According to the table, the "colspan" has one td child, other rows have more than one children (td). So, we skipped based on that.
$cells->length will return the child count of the element (No. of td)

Comment: Instead of checking the length on every iteration, you could simply exclude those elements from the original set.

Comment: THANKS Dhayal makes perfect sense now

Answer (score 1):

## use xpath to exclude elements with `colspan` attributes

So instead of:

```
$cells = $rows->getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Use:

```
$cells = $xpath->query('td[not(@colspan)]', $rows);
```

Comment: very simple and practical. Thank you sir